# VS Code doesn't add command line on path permanently on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS code 1.8.1 on Mac 10.12.3 (16D32). After launch vscode, I run `cmd shift p` to open command search field. Then run `Install code command in Path`. I can see the code got added on PATH but it got removed after I close vs code. Is there a way to add it permanently?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am assuming you've checked [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac).

VSCode application generally resides in `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`.

Follow these steps to access VSCode through `code` on shell.

1. Open bash_profile page

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/paths
   ```
2. Add an extra line in the list of PATH folders as

   ```
   /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/
   ```
3. Exit from vi: Esc > :wq! > Enter Key

Restart shell. Then do `echo $PATH` to confirm VSCode has been added successfully.

Check code command is added by typing `which code`. You should see VSCode path printed on screen.

Try [this link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) if it doesn't work out.

**Edit:** I am using version 1.9.1 and after I ran `Install code command in Path` it got added permanently.

Comment: The location was different for me. On MacOS you can open up VSCode manually, enter the shortcut `COMMAND + SHIFT + P` to open the command window and type in `>Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`. Then goto terminal and type in `which code` and add the value from `which` to `/etc/paths`

Comment: @DeanMeehan The invisible helper 

Answer (score 59):

So I've just had this issue during setup of a new laptop and found a simple (but slightly embarrassing) solution that worked for me. After faffing about with it for way too long I noticed I had left it in Downloads. I moved the .app file to /Applications and ran the command-line install function again and now the "code" command persists.

Comment: None of the above worked for me so I did a lookup in Downloads and found out that I did the same.

Comment: this is the droid I was looking for

Comment: Moved mine to /Applications and it didn't help.

Answer (score 21):

Add this to your ~/.bash_profile

`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"`

source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio Code

```
rm /usr/local/bin/code
ln -s "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" /usr/local/bin/code
```

Visual Studio Code - Insiders

```
rm /usr/local/bin/code-insiders
ln -s "/Applications/Visual Studio Code - Insiders.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" /usr/local/bin/code-insiders
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that `Visual Studio Code.app` was not in the `Applications` folder, but rather in the `Downloads` folder. Moving it there and re-running the `add to path` command fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

### For Big Sur:

From the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac):

> Note: Since zsh became the default shell in macOS Catalina, **run the**
> **following commands** to add VS Code to your path:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zprofile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code) export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio
Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin" EOF
```

I did this and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Visual Studio Code - Insiders 1.23.0 on a Mac/Mac OS 10.10.5 Yosemite. I added the "Shell Command: Install 'code-insiders' command in PATH" from within VSC - Insiders. From the terminal in any directory I just add 'code-insiders .' and it launches in VSC - Insiders without issue.

Hope that helps.